# ALMotionProxy::moveToward() of NAOqi does not work as exptected

Tags: c++, nao-robot

I want to move a NAO by sending velocity inputs through the *NAOqi* *C++ API* [ALMotionProxy::moveToward()](http://doc.aldebaran.com/1-14/naoqi/motion/control-walk-api.html#ALMotionProxy::moveToward__floatCR.floatCR.floatCR), that requires a normalized velocity along x-y-z. I generate these commands through a joystick, so that they are automatically normalized in the range [-1,1]. 
However, when I set the corresponding values in the method, NAO moves only if the values are exactly -1 or +1. For all the other values, instead, it does not move at all. This looks like an unusual behaviour because, using the moveToward block in Choregraphe, the NAO actually moves also for values between -1 and 1.

I'm printing the generated joystick commands before them to be provided to the *moveToward()* method, so I have already checked that they are properly acquired. I'm commanding NAO only along x and z direction.

Pasting the code here is unnecessary, the part of interest is simply the method call

```
motionProxy.moveToward(fvel_x,0.0f,fvel_z);
```

Please tell me if you need further information. Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. There is a conflicting issue between the Naoqi 1.14 version and OpenCV, running on Ubuntu 14.04 (actually, Naoqi documentation does not ensure support for newer OS). Running the same code on Ubuntu 12.04 solved my problem.